# possible to manually copy printer driver from win 7 to win 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, drivers, network-printer

I have a venerable but still very serviceable HP6840 network printer, and my old 64 bit Windows 7 box has a driver for it and happily prints to it.

However, my windows 10 laptop doesn't find a driver for it. Attempts to manually locate a driver for it have also failed. The nearest I found was a 32 bit driver which the installer rejected.

Is there any way to manually copy the driver files across from one system to the other? I'm really loathe to replace the printer, it works really fine and I absolutely hate replacing gear when it is as unnecessary as this.

If so how would I find the correct set of files to copy? the printer doesn't show up in device manager on the Win 7 box, for some reason.

Both are 64 bit systems.

Comment: I go to HP web site and offers me a driver for Win 10 64 bit. As the driver is built in to Windows it is directions on how to set it up. A more generic answer is that printers emulate well known printers. You can install the generic driver.

Comment: https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-deskjet-6840-printer-series/385457

Comment: So the laptop "sees it" on the network, but you cannot find the driver? If "yes" you can try the generic HP PCL 6 driver; if "no" setting wifi network to "private" might be worth trying

Answer (score 0):

> However, my windows 10 laptop doesn't find a driver for it. Attempts
> to manually locate a driver for it have also failed. The nearest I
> found was a 32 bit driver which the installer rejected

Copying the driver does not work if it is not properly installed with bringing it over.

So using the printer on Windows 10 (nominally 64-bit) is not going to work.

Two options:

1. New Printer (probably best).
2. Windows 7 virtual machine, install the driver, print from Windows 7.  Print to PDF if you need the file on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to backup the existing/running driver in Windows 7 for the purpose of reusing that backup by importing it into Windows 10 you may utilize `dism`.

[DISM - Deployment Image Servicing and Management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/what-is-dism?view=windows-11) is a command-line tool that offers diverse commands to create backups and to deploy whole windows operating systems as well as single packages, like for example drivers.

It requires to be run with administrator privileges.

Exemplary procedure:

1. On the Windows 7 install open a CMD or PowerShell as Administrator.
2. Type:

```
dism /Online /Get-Drivers /format:table
```

... this will list you all non-system-default-drivers aka manually installed ones in a table overview.

3. Identify the driver. If it is not obvious from `Class Name` and `Provider Name` look up your printer-properties e.g. via the device manager. The properties provide information which driver is loaded for the device. Once you have that information and ensured that the driver is indeed listed in the output of former performed `dism` `get-drivers` command, you can go on and export all the manually installed drivers to a directory of your choice either into an existing folder or by optionally creating a folder first.

Optional - create a `Drivers`-folder in your user-directory:

```
mkdir %UserProfile%\Drivers
```

... then export the drivers:

```
dism /Online /Export-driver /Destination:%UserProfile%\Drivers
```

After this you may copy the folder onto the other system (Windows 10). There you can simply select the printer listed in the device-manager, open the properties and choose to `Update driver` and selecting the given driver from the former made backup.

If both Systems are in the same PC and you have access to both drives/systems you could also use the `dism /add-driver` command directly from Windows 7 to force-feed it into the Windows 10 installation. This is risky. If you wish to do so, please ask a separate question precisely for this scenario.